# SIGTERM handling issue in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, signals, daemon

Here is a code which works well on Yosemite 10.10.4 but doesn't work in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion:

```
    void signal_handler(const int sigid)
    {
      NSLog(@"signal received: %d", sigid);
    } 
...
    signal(SIGTERM, (sig_t)signal_handler); // registering signal
```

signal_handler callback function is not calling in 10.8 when shutdown Mac Mini.
How to fix the problem above?

Comment: Just so you know, the `SIGKILL` signal can't be cought, and neither can the `SIGSTOP` signal.

Comment: What does `NSLog` do?  It should not call - directly or indirectly - non-async-signal-safe functions.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sigaction.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/sigaction

Comment: What do you mean by *[...] when shutdown Mac Mini [...]*? There's no requirement that `SIGTERM` is sent to a process when the system is shutting down.

Comment: if your process is daemon or agent then you can handle SIGTERM